# Primefaces selectOneMenu f:selectitem(s) do not update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 6.0 and my Problem is following:
First of all, here is the Code Snippet

**.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
<h:head><title>HelpMeStackoverflow</title></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
...
<p:outputLabel for="vorname1" value="Vorname 1"/>
<p:inputText id="vorname1" value="#{bean.p1vorname}"/>
<p:message for="vorname1"/>

<p:outputLabel for="zuname1" value="Zuname 1"/>
<p:inputText id="zuname1" value="#{bean.p1zuname}"/>
<p:message for="zuname1"/>

<p:outputLabel for="vorname2" value="Vorname 2"/>
<p:inputText id="vorname2" value="#{bean.p2vorname}"/>
<p:message for="vorname2"/>

<p:outputLabel for="zuname2" value="Zuname 2"/>
<p:inputText id="zuname2" value="#{bean.p2zuname}"/>
<p:message for="zuname2"/>

<p:selectOneMenu id="dropdownvalue"
                 value="#{bean.dropdownvalue}"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Bitte ausw&auml;hlen!">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bitte ausw&auml;hlen" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItem
            itemLabel="#{bean.p1vorname} #{bean.p1zuname}"
            itemValue="1"
            itemDisabled="#{bean.p1zuname.isEmpty()}"/>
    <f:selectItem
            itemLabel="#{bean.p2vorname} #{bean.p2zuname}"
            itemValue="2"
            itemDisabled="#{bean.p2zuname.isEmpty()}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="dropdownvalue"/>
...
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

...
private String p1zuname;
private String p1vorname;
private String p2zuname;
private String p2vorname;
...

// autogenerated getters/setters

}
```

[Empty Strings in Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhgfq.png)

The Dropdown contains just empty Strings. I debugged into the set*-Methods of the Attributes and the values are in. The Problems here seems to be either the p:selectOneMenu or the f:selectItem.

Used:

- JPA 2.1
- Mojarra 2.2.1
- Tomcat 9.0.0.M21
- everything under Java 1.8

Comment: Hi, [mcve] please. Problem can not be reproduced with just this code

Comment: Thanks for response,I Don't know what else you need here. Getters/Setters are autogenerated and the rest does not seem to be necessary

Comment: I need an [mcve]... Also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info  If you think nothing else is needed, well, then ok... Can't help any further then.

Comment: Wasn't my intention to be mean about your constructive hints. I'm going to add some more Informations about my example.

Comment: I know you did not want to be mean. Did not take it a such.I'm just not going to try to convince people if they have other opinions about the needed code. Takes too much time. But don't add 'some more information', male it a [mcve]

Comment: I extended myexample - should be easier now to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I added some ajax to all my p:inputTexts

```
<p:ajax event="blur" process="vorname1 zuname1 vorname2 zuname2"
                            update="dropdownvalue"/>
```

Now it works as it should.